# Create ref for elements in loop

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have an array of react elements that I output using the map function:

```
{ elemsList.map((item, i) => { 
    return (
        <div 
           key={i}
           ref={refsArr[i]}
           data-grid={item.props["data-grid"]}
           onClick={e => doubleClickHandler(item.key, e)}
           style={{ 
                backgroundColor: i === selectedComponent ? '#828EE3' : "#102f6a", 
                color: "#fff", 
                height: "100%",
           }}
        >
            {item}
        </div>
    )}
) }
```

I need to create a ref for each of the elements of this array. I tried to do it using useRef passing an array there:

```
const refsArr = useRef([])
refsArr.current = elemsList.map((item, i) => refsArr.current[i] ?? setTimeout(createRef(), 5000))
...
{ elemsList.map((item, i) => { 
    return (
        <div 
           key={i}
           ref={refsArr[i]}
           data-grid={item.props["data-grid"]}
           onClick={e => doubleClickHandler(item.key, e)}
           style={{ 
                backgroundColor: i === selectedComponent ? '#828EE3' : "#102f6a", 
                color: "#fff", 
                height: "100%",
           }}
        >
            {item}
        </div>
    )}
) }
```

The problem is that when I try to output my ref array to the console, instead of a normal ref, I get an object with the following (or similar) content:

```
{ current: [53] }
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: what you got in **elemsList**

Comment: @NaveenNizam i've got only div elements

Answer (score 0):

you can use the combination of `useRef` and `createRef`.

```js
const refsArr = useRef(elemsList.map(() => createRef()));
useEffect(() => {
  const classnames = refsArr.current.map(
    ref => ref.current.classname
  );
  console.log(classnames);
}, []);

//...
{ elemsList.map((item, i) => { 
    return (
        <div 
           key={i}
           ref={refsArr[i]}
           data-grid={item.props["data-grid"]}
           onClick={e => doubleClickHandler(item.key, e)}
           style={{ 
                backgroundColor: i === selectedComponent ? '#828EE3' : "#102f6a", 
                color: "#fff", 
                height: "100%",
           }}
        >
            {item}
        </div>
    )}
) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work:

```
ref={refsArr[i]}
```

The `ref` prop expects a mutable ref object, or a ref callback.

```
refsArr[i] // undefined
```

Is going to return `undefined`, which is not a mutable ref object, or a ref callback.

Instead, pass a callback function that accepts the element and assigns it to the refsArr at the index.

```
ref={(element) => {
  refsArr.current[i] = element;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `refsArr[i]` as the `ref` attribute, but `refsArr` is a `ref` object itself, so you need to access its current property first. You should use `refsArr.current[i]` instead.

And you are not updating your `refsArr` when your `elemsList` changes, which may cause stale or missing refs. You should use `useEffect` to sync your `refsArr` with your `elemsList`.

You can use `useEffect` and a callback ref to create and update your `refsArr` dynamically. For example:

```
const App = ({ elemsList }) => {
  const refsArr = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    refsArr.current = refsArr.current.slice(0, elemsList.length);
  }, [elemsList]);

  return (
    <>
      {elemsList.map((item, i) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={i}
            ref={(el) => (refsArr.current[i] = el)}
            data-grid={item.props["data-grid"]}
            onClick={(e) => doubleClickHandler(item.key, e)}
            style={{
              backgroundColor: i === selectedComponent ? "#828EE3" : "#102f6a",
              color: "#fff",
              height: "100%",
            }}
          >
            {item}
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```